# How to create an number line control?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpf-controls, controls

I'm planning to create a number-line control similar to the image below (only one of them):

[image]

I'm creating a program where the children can detect where's the position's number. I mean, instruct them to write the number 4 (and the boy writes a vertical line).

The idea is when the cursor is on the control, it shows a vertical line. And when the user presses OK, returns with an event the X position and hold it the line.

Do you know if there's a similar control on the web?

Comment: Your description reminds me of [Slider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754230(v=vs.100).aspx) control.

Comment: hey, that's true.. I didn't even think that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use a Slider with a new template.
[How to Create/Apply a Slider Template](http://codingsense.wordpress.com/2010/02/01/customize-a-slider-in-wpf-step-by-step-tutorial/)

Comment: that's great. But there only one thing I couldn't made it. How to set the vertical line?

Comment: You can make anything in a template. make it a border, rectangle, grid, path, etc.